# Вывод списка объектов в API Яндекс карты

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

Доброго всем времени суток! Подскажите пожалуйста, подключаю API Яндекс карт и пытаюсь вывести список объектов как в примере, но ничего не получается, ссылку на документацию и код прилагаю. В JS не шарю, но сделать надо, уважаемые форумчане, выручите пожалуйста! https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/object_list/

````
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Размещение карты на странице.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/groups.js"type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Размещение карты на странице</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
        ymaps.ready(init);
        function init() {
        // Создание экземпляра карты.
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [50.443705, 30.530946],
            zoom: 14
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        // Контейнер для меню.
        menu = $('<ul class="menu"/>');       
        for (var i = 0, l = groups.length; i < l; i++) {
            createMenuGroup(groups[i]);
        }
        function createMenuGroup (group) {
        // Пункт меню.
            var menuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + group.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Коллекция для геообъектов группы.
            collection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, { preset: group.style }),
        // Контейнер для подменю.
            submenu = $('<ul class="submenu"/>');
        // Добавляем коллекцию на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
        // Добавляем подменю.
            menuItem
            .append(submenu)
            // Добавляем пункт в меню.
            .appendTo(menu)
            // По клику удаляем/добавляем коллекцию на карту и скрываем/отображаем подменю.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (collection.getParent()) {
                    myMap.geoObjects.remove(collection);
                    submenu.hide();
                } else {
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
                    submenu.show();
                }
            });
            for (var j = 0, m = group.items.length; j < m; j++) {
                createSubMenu(group.items[j], collection, submenu);
            }
        }
        function createSubMenu (item, collection, submenu) {
        // Пункт подменю.
            var submenuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + item.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Создаем метку.
            placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(item.center, { balloonContent: item.name });
        // Добавляем метку в коллекцию.
            collection.add(placemark);
        // Добавляем пункт в подменю.
            submenuItem
            .appendTo(submenu)
            // При клике по пункту подменю открываем/закрываем баллун у метки.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (!placemark.balloon.isOpen()) {
                    placemark.balloon.open();
                } else {
                    placemark.balloon.close();
                }
                return false;
            });
        }

    // Добавляем меню в тэг BODY.
        menu.appendTo($('body'));
    // Выставляем масштаб карты чтобы были видны все группы.
        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
        }
    </script>

<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:300px"></div>
</body>

</html>```

В groups.js список объектов

```// Группы объектов
var groups = [
        {
            name: "Покушайки",
            style: "islands#greenIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.50955, 30.60791],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Калинка-Малинка&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.429083, 30.521708],
                    name: "Бар &quot;Сало-бар&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.450843, 30.498271],
                    name: "Абсент-бар &quot;Палата №6&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454834, 30.516498],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Спотыкач&quot;"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Оригинальные музейчики",
            style: "islands#orangeIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.443334, 30.520163],
                    name: "Музей грамзаписи и старинных музыкальных инструментов"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.446977, 30.505269],
                    name: "Музей истории медицины или Анатомический театр"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.452512, 30.530889],
                    name: "Музей воды. Водно-информационный центр"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Красивости",
            style: "islands#blueIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.45987, 30.516174],
                    name: "Замок Ричарда-Львиное сердце"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.445049, 30.528598],
                    name: "&quot;Дом с химерами&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.449156, 30.511809],
                    name: "Дом Рыцаря"
                }
            ]}
    ];```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да все нормально в примере

```js
// Группы объектов
var groups = [
        {
            name: "Известные памятники",
            style: "islands#redIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.426472, 30.563022],
                    name: "Монумент &quot;Родина-Мать&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.45351, 30.516489],
                    name: "Памятник &quot;Богдану Хмельницкому&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454433, 30.529874],
                    name: "Арка Дружбы народов"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Покушайки",
            style: "islands#greenIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.50955, 30.60791],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Калинка-Малинка&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.429083, 30.521708],
                    name: "Бар &quot;Сало-бар&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.450843, 30.498271],
                    name: "Абсент-бар &quot;Палата №6&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454834, 30.516498],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Спотыкач&quot;"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Оригинальные музейчики",
            style: "islands#orangeIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.443334, 30.520163],
                    name: "Музей грамзаписи и старинных музыкальных инструментов"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.446977, 30.505269],
                    name: "Музей истории медицины или Анатомический театр"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.452512, 30.530889],
                    name: "Музей воды. Водно-информационный центр"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Красивости",
            style: "islands#blueIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.45987, 30.516174],
                    name: "Замок Ричарда-Львиное сердце"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.445049, 30.528598],
                    name: "&quot;Дом с химерами&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.449156, 30.511809],
                    name: "Дом Рыцаря"
                }
            ]}
    ];


ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {

    // Создание экземпляра карты.
    var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [50.443705, 30.530946],
            zoom: 14
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        // Контейнер для меню.
        menu = $('<ul class="menu"/>');
        
    for (var i = 0, l = groups.length; i < l; i++) {
        createMenuGroup(groups[i]);
    }

    function createMenuGroup (group) {
        // Пункт меню.
        var menuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + group.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Коллекция для геообъектов группы.
            collection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, { preset: group.style }),
        // Контейнер для подменю.
            submenu = $('<ul class="submenu"/>');

        // Добавляем коллекцию на карту.
        myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
        // Добавляем подменю.
        menuItem
            .append(submenu)
            // Добавляем пункт в меню.
            .appendTo(menu)
            // По клику удаляем/добавляем коллекцию на карту и скрываем/отображаем подменю.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (collection.getParent()) {
                    myMap.geoObjects.remove(collection);
                    submenu.hide();
                } else {
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
                    submenu.show();
                }
            });
        for (var j = 0, m = group.items.length; j < m; j++) {
            createSubMenu(group.items[j], collection, submenu);
        }
    }

    function createSubMenu (item, collection, submenu) {
        // Пункт подменю.
        var submenuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + item.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Создаем метку.
            placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(item.center, { balloonContent: item.name });

        // Добавляем метку в коллекцию.
        collection.add(placemark);
        // Добавляем пункт в подменю.
        submenuItem
            .appendTo(submenu)
            // При клике по пункту подменю открываем/закрываем баллун у метки.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (!placemark.balloon.isOpen()) {
                    placemark.balloon.open();
                } else {
                    placemark.balloon.close();
                }
                return false;
            });
    }

    // Добавляем меню в тэг BODY.
    menu.appendTo($('body'));
    // Выставляем масштаб карты чтобы были видны все группы.
    myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
}
```

```css
        html, body{
            width: 100%; padding: 0; margin: 0;
            font-family: Arial;
        }

        #map {
            width: 95%;
            height: 250px;
        }
            /* Оформление меню (начало)*/
        .menu {
            list-style: none;
            padding: 5px;

            margin: 0;
        }
        .submenu {
            list-style: none;

            margin: 0 0 0 20px;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .submenu li {
            font-size: 90%;
        }
```

```html
<script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://yandex.st/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
```

Ну а в Вашем не хватает JQuery

```html
<head>
    <title>Размещение карты на странице.</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <script src="http://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.0/?load=package.full&lang=ru-RU" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var groups = [
        {
            name: "Покушайки",
            style: "islands#greenIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.50955, 30.60791],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Калинка-Малинка&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.429083, 30.521708],
                    name: "Бар &quot;Сало-бар&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.450843, 30.498271],
                    name: "Абсент-бар &quot;Палата №6&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.454834, 30.516498],
                    name: "Ресторан &quot;Спотыкач&quot;"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Оригинальные музейчики",
            style: "islands#orangeIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.443334, 30.520163],
                    name: "Музей грамзаписи и старинных музыкальных инструментов"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.446977, 30.505269],
                    name: "Музей истории медицины или Анатомический театр"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.452512, 30.530889],
                    name: "Музей воды. Водно-информационный центр"
                }
            ]},
        {
            name: "Красивости",
            style: "islands#blueIcon",
            items: [
                {
                    center: [50.45987, 30.516174],
                    name: "Замок Ричарда-Львиное сердце"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.445049, 30.528598],
                    name: "&quot;Дом с химерами&quot;"
                },
                {
                    center: [50.449156, 30.511809],
                    name: "Дом Рыцаря"
                }
            ]}
    ];
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Размещение карты на странице</h2>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        // Как только будет загружен API и готов DOM, выполняем инициализацию
        ymaps.ready(init);
        function init() {
        // Создание экземпляра карты.
        var myMap = new ymaps.Map('map', {
            center: [50.443705, 30.530946],
            zoom: 14
        }, {
            searchControlProvider: 'yandex#search'
        }),
        // Контейнер для меню.
        menu = $('<ul class="menu"/>');       
        for (var i = 0, l = groups.length; i < l; i++) {
            createMenuGroup(groups[i]);
        }
        function createMenuGroup (group) {
        // Пункт меню.
            var menuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + group.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Коллекция для геообъектов группы.
            collection = new ymaps.GeoObjectCollection(null, { preset: group.style }),
        // Контейнер для подменю.
            submenu = $('<ul class="submenu"/>');
        // Добавляем коллекцию на карту.
            myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
        // Добавляем подменю.
            menuItem
            .append(submenu)
            // Добавляем пункт в меню.
            .appendTo(menu)
            // По клику удаляем/добавляем коллекцию на карту и скрываем/отображаем подменю.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (collection.getParent()) {
                    myMap.geoObjects.remove(collection);
                    submenu.hide();
                } else {
                    myMap.geoObjects.add(collection);
                    submenu.show();
                }
            });
            for (var j = 0, m = group.items.length; j < m; j++) {
                createSubMenu(group.items[j], collection, submenu);
            }
        }
        function createSubMenu (item, collection, submenu) {
        // Пункт подменю.
            var submenuItem = $('<li><a href="#">' + item.name + '</a></li>'),
        // Создаем метку.
            placemark = new ymaps.Placemark(item.center, { balloonContent: item.name });
        // Добавляем метку в коллекцию.
            collection.add(placemark);
        // Добавляем пункт в подменю.
            submenuItem
            .appendTo(submenu)
            // При клике по пункту подменю открываем/закрываем баллун у метки.
            .find('a')
            .bind('click', function () {
                if (!placemark.balloon.isOpen()) {
                    placemark.balloon.open();
                } else {
                    placemark.balloon.close();
                }
                return false;
            });
        }

    // Добавляем меню в тэг BODY.
        menu.appendTo($('body'));
    // Выставляем масштаб карты чтобы были видны все группы.
        myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds());
        }
    </script>

<div id="map" style="width:600px; height:300px"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: сейчас ребутнул страницу со сбросом кэша и заработало... просто фэйспалм...
пардонюсь за бессмысленный топик...

Comment: @ДядяВаня У Вас JQuery нет

Comment: в таких случаях закрывают опечаткой обычно

Comment: У Автора не опечатка а не хватает опыта. Я и показал в чем ошибка

Comment: @AzizUmarov да, я не разбираюсь в JS, опыта действительно не было ранее, хотел бы уточнить про JQuery, зачем его подключать, если сейчас в локалхосте отработало? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: отработало потому что кто то подключил.  И скорее всего на локалхосте у вас пример имеет JQuery